# The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (no reply)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, oop

```
getString(comment) {
    const authorName = comment.getAuthor().getName();
    if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;
    return `${comment.getMessage()} by ${authorName} (replied to 
    ${this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())})`;
}
toString() {
    const authorName = this.getAuthor().getName();
    if (!this.getRepliedTo()) {
        return `${this.message} by ${authorName}`;
    }
    return this.getString(this);
}
}
```

While, this block of code is giving me an error(hidden unit tests).
What exactly is wrong?

***should handle toString
The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (no reply)***

Comment: Why do you ask the same question several times? I googled the question's title and found one deleted and one undeleted question with the same contents. If you didn't get a useful answer then you should consider working on your question. Providing more context helps. How do you get that error? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, thats true. The only thing is that there is no other way I can ask it.